# Limit image size that can be uploaded

Tags: 2013, image-upload

I'm trying to decrease the image size that users can submit to an image library. When a user adds an image, it will be displayed on an aspx page. I am already limiting how big the picture can be on there by defining a class, but is there a way that I can limit it in the library too?

I've seen some ways on how to do it in Visual Studio, but I don't have access to that yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Unfortunately,** there is no OOTB solution to can limit the uploaded file size for a specific library.

> **Note:** Max file upload size is defined on a **web application scope** in
>   Central Administration > General Settings.
>
> [image]
>
> The default file size is **250 MB** and the max file size in 2013 is
>   **2 GB** and for 2016 is **10 GB** for more details check [compare SharePoint 2016 List and Library limits with other SharePoint
>   versions.](https://blog.devoworx.net/2016/07/05/compare-sharepoint-2016-list-library-limits-with-sharepoint-2013-2010/)

---

**Workaround**

The available workaround solution is to use **Event Receiver** on `ItemAdding`

For more details check

- [Developing an Event Receiver for a Document Library](https://karinebosch.wordpress.com/walkthroughs/event-receivers-walkthrough2/)
- [Limit file Uploading size for Document Library](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/4ae013fd-57ab-4219-9caf-27495d564602/sharepoint-2010-limit-file-uploading-size-for-document-library?forum=sharepointgeneralprevious)

Comment: The last link was what I was looking at before I asked this question! I'm just not sure how to apply it. With a CEWP?

Comment: As a short answer, you can't!! as I mentioned in my answer! the available workaround is Event receiver that is server side, CEWP only holds CSS and client-side code like JS, Jquery!

Comment: ahhh, gotcha. I should have looked at the first link a little more carefully. Thanks for the information. I'll have to try something else out then!

Answer (score 1):

You can limit the file size upload to SharePoint library by applying the below steps:

Login with Farm Admin user on the central admin.
1 - Click on Application Management.
2 - Click on Manage Web Application.
3 - Click on the Web Application ( the one you want to change the file size).
4 - From Ribbon, click on General Settings.
5- On this pop up browse all the way down and type the value into Maximum Upload Size text box.
6- Click OK

As per the below link:
https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/34132.sharepoint-2016-increase-file-size-limit.aspx

Comment: I'm a SCA so I don't have web application settings level of rights. Plus, I just wanted to limit one library. Thanks for the info though!